# LaTeX in the web (equations enumeration)

Tags: html, latex, mathjax

I have a web where I put some equations using MathJAX in LaTeX language. The thing is that all goes right, but when I write something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  The equation...
\end{equation}
```

it doesn't enumerate the equation, while using it in a pure LaTeX environment, it perfectly enumerates the equations.
I wonder to know if I'm wrong and if there is a way to enumerate the equations (at the right side) in an html file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering), you need to turn this on explicitly like so:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

This will give you AMS-style numbering. You can also specify "all" to number every displayed equation.